# Using generate_series() to produce 30 day date ranges for each day?

Tags: postgresql, set, date-arithmetic, generate-series

My goal is to create a table that looks something like this using PostgreSQL:

```
date           date_start        date_end
12/16/2015     11/17/2015        12/16/2015
12/17/2015     11/18/2015        12/17/2015
etc.
```

So that I can then join to a different table to get the aggregations for each date on a rolling 30 day window. I've been doing some research and I think `generate_series()` is what I want to use, but I am unsure.

Comment: I would prefer another solution: One "helper" table with column `add` and row values 1..30. Then you can get list of 30 dates around some base date with `DATEADD(day, <add>, base_date)`.

Comment: Why is `date_end` constant? (12/16/2015), should be moving, too, for a "rolling window".

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT '2015-12-16'::date + g - 30 AS date_start
     , '2015-12-16'::date + g      AS date_end
FROM   generate_series (0, 25) g; -- number of rows
```

I skipped the redundant `date` column. (You shouldn't use a basic type name as identifier anyways.)

There is a variant of [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) that works with timestamps, but the simple version generating `integer` numbers is just as good for dates. Maybe even better because you avoid possible confusion with time zones.

Always use the ISO 8601 format for date literals, which is unambiguous with any `datestyle` or locale settings.

Related:

- [Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107495/3684)